# How to show an another form with picture box on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form say Form1 having a button. On that button click i am showing another form (say Form2)with a pictureBox . When i run form2 it show me image properly but when i click on button of form1 my form2 getting display without image.

```
    //Form 1
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {  Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.show();}
```

Comment: where is image coming from?

Comment: i just attached in a picture box from my desktop only

Comment: Delete and attach picturebox again

Comment: show the image related code of `form2`.

Comment: @Shaharyar i have attached image through properties

Comment: There is no image related code because it is designer generated as he already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `form2` constructor:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponenet();
    picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\img.jpg");    //added
}
```

Comment: What is the size of picture box? and Aren't there any other controls over it?

Comment: height & width resp. 100, 50. No other control is there on form

Comment: Its really difficult to identify the problem without any code. I can only suggest you to delete the `Form2` and add it again, add `picturebox` and this time do not attach the image using designer view. Attach the image using the code I provided you.